# Sampling Implicit functions

Tags: sampling

Consider an implicit function like `f`

```
dist[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - #1)^2. + (y - #2)^2.] &
f[x_, y_] = dist[-1, 0][x, y] dist[1, 0][x, y]
```

How to sample points on `f[x,y]==c` without explicitly solving for y?

---

`f[x,y]==c` is a Cassini oval and looks like

`Animate[ContourPlot[f[x, y] == t, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100], {t, 0.6, 2, 0.1}]`

[image: fig1. <code>f[x,y]==c</code> for various c]

Comment: `How to sample points on` But `ContourPlot` always did that. So you can just read the samples? `t = 1;
p = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == t, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]; p[[1,1,1]]` gives you the (x,y) data. I also do not understand why you do not want to solve for `y` explicitly as function of `x` and then do the sampling?

Comment: Do you mean sample *at equal distances* ?

Comment: @andre314 any which way but say uniformly

Comment: @Nasser after solving one has to restructure the different values for the same x and then put them together etc-there's some post proc. involved. Extracting from contour plot was what i was looking for....if you post i'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sampling is done by `ContourPlot`. To extract the data:

```
dist[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - #1)^2 + (y - #2)^2] &;
f[x_, y_] = dist[-1, 0][x, y] dist[1, 0][x, y];
t = 1;
p = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == t, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
p[[1, 1, 1]]
```

This gives the `{x,y}` data

You can change the spacing by changing the `PlotPoints`

```
 p = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == t, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 5];
 p[[1, 1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also `Contours` option could be used to control this.

Answer (score 4):

> How to sample points on `f[x, y] == c` without explicitly solving for `y`?

In old versions of *Mathematica*, Nasser's method is what I would have used. Nowadays, I would use the `MeshFunctions` option of `ContourPlot[]` for the purpose. Observe the following (and note also my rewrite of your implicit Cartesian equation for the Cassinian ovals):

```
With[{t = 8/9}, (* you can omit the MeshStyle setting if desired *)
     ContourPlot[Product[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, p], {p, {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}}] == t,
                 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> {20, 1}, 
                 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshStyle -> ColorData[97, 4]]
```

[image: points on Cassinian oval]

```
Dimensions[pts = Cases[Normal[%], Point[p_] :> p, ∞]]
   {32, 2}

ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: sampled points]

Comment: This does not work in (my) V12.1.0 (MacOS). It should, though, so +1.  AFAICT, only the last of the `MeshFunctions` is used.  The example in the docs (last one under Options > Mesh) does not produce the output shown, either.  I guess it's a bug.

Comment: I'm still stuck on 11.2, so it's a little sad to hear that it doesn't work as expected in newer versions. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 4):

For random sampling, one can use regions and `RandomPoint`:

```
dist[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - #1)^2. + (y - #2)^2.] &;
ff[x_, y_] = dist[-1, 0][x, y] dist[1, 0][x, y];

reg = DiscretizeGraphics@
   ContourPlot[ff[x, y] == 1/2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];

pts = RandomPoint[reg, 100];
Graphics[{
  Point@pts
  }, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

One can also use `ImplicitRegion`, which results in highly accurate `pts` at a cost of a longer computation:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[ff[x, y] == 1/2, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}];
```

You can compare the accuracy with

```
ff @@@ pts - 1/2  (* change 1/2 to suit contour level *)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) can work here:

```
P = {x, y} /. FindInstance[f[x, y] == 0.6, {x, y}, Reals, 10^2]

(*    {{1.09138, 0.269467}, {-1.24726, 0.100017}, {-0.922089, 0.298462},
       ...
       {-0.696263, 0.177498}, {0.972681, -0.299466}, {0.70461, -0.187505}}    *)

ListPlot[P]
```

[image]

### old answer

Using exact exponents `2` instead of `2.`:

```
dist[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - #1)^2 + (y - #2)^2] &;
f[x_, y_] = dist[-1, 0][x, y] dist[1, 0][x, y];
```

Use `Solve`:

```
Y[t_, x_] = y /. Solve[f[x, y] == t, y, Reals]
```

Example:

```
Y[0.6, 0.7]
{-0.182084, 0.182084}
```

You can now make tables of $(x,y)$ pairs for given $t$.